# store grails domain variable in springsecurity session object on login

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using spring security.  I have a user object which does not contain a variable that will need to be displayed on several pages when the user logs in.  The domains look like:

```
class User {
    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    Integer securityQuestion
    String securityAnswer

}

class Profile {
   User user
   String displayMe  //this is actually a calculated transient string based on some other info
}
```

Profile and User are separate classes.  I need to store profile.displayMe in the session for use in some gsps.  I don't have one big User domain because the domain model has several profile types and combining them all into a giant User domain was messy.  Combining the domains in order to have User.displayMe isn't an option.

Where in springsecurity would I store profile.displayMe in the session?  I'm not that familiar with springsecurity yet so I'll need some specific help, such as 'in the auth method of LoginController.groovy (the default login controller of springsecurity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a custom UserDetailsService. See the docs, http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/userDetailsService.html if you're using 2.0 or http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html if you're using 1.x